# Why are Ethtool WOL settings reset on startup?

Tags: 12.04, ethernet, wakeonlan

I installed `ethtool` and ran `ethtool -s eth1 wol g` to allow my server (ubuntu 12.04) to wake up on LAN (WOL). This setting is for some reason reset every startup, so I added the above command to `/etc/rc.local`.

But why is this setting reset on every startup? Is this a bug or is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Community Ubuntu Documentation on WakeOnLan](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan) states that it is a normal behavior - you have to, in one way or the other, set the option after every reboot. I am using the `/etc/network/interfaces` method, as it is described in the article, in two machines and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and tried the "Comunity Ubuntu Documentation on WakeOnLine" but that did not work.

Make it persistent
systemd.link

Link-level configuration is possible through systemd-networkd#link files. The actual setup is performed by the net_setup_link udev builtin. Add the WakeOnLan option to the network link file:

/etc/systemd/network/50-wired.link

[Match]
MACAddress=yourmacaddr

[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
WakeOnLan=magic

Now boot with WOL every time.